# PostgreSQL - Error: "invalid input syntax for type bytea"

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to PostgreSQL so I apologize if the question is elementary.

During PostgreSQL database restore, from sql file, I am getting an error "invalid input syntax for type bytea" and I believe the data is not copied to the table, i.e. the table is empty.

This is the error message:

```
    2015-02-20 08:56:14 EST ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
    2015-02-20 08:56:14 EST CONTEXT:  COPY ir_ui_menu, line 166, column web_icon_data: "\x6956424f5277304b47676f414141414e5355684555674141414751414141426b43414d41414142485047566d4141414143..."
2015-02-20 08:56:14 EST STATEMENT:  COPY ir_ui_menu (id, parent_id, name, icon, create_uid, create_date, write_date, write_uid, web_icon_data, web_icon, sequence, web_icon_hover, web_icon_hover_data) FROM stdin;
```

The database backup dump is created like this:

```
pg_dump -U user_name database_name -f backup_file.sql
```

The database restore is done like this:

```
psql -U user_name -d destination_db -f backup_file.sql
```

Source database (to get backup from) is PostgreSQL version 9.1.15 on one server and destination (to restore to) database is PostgreSQL 8.3.4, on another server.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the offending SQL statement?

Comment: I think it's COPY, the error briefly showed in command window, so I did not copy whole message.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment: we need the offending statement in order to help you.

Comment: @janfoeh   The backup sql file is 2.5GB in size and I tried to open it with Notepad and Notepad++ but got an error that file is too big to open.

Comment: The backup file wouldn't help you anyway, as long as you don't know which line to look for. Find the location of the Postgres server log file and check there.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked in the log file and found the place of error message. I have updated my question content here with the error message.

Comment: How was the dump created, and how are you trying to restore it?

Comment: @janfoeh I have updated my question content with the information about dump and restore.

Comment: Thanks. Are the dump source and the restore target both running the same version of Postgres? Which ones?

Comment: @janfoeh I have updated my question content with the information about database versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restoring a dump from a newer version of Postgres onto an older is quite often problematic, and there is no automated way that I am aware of. Making this work will most likely require editing the dump file manually.

Specifically, Postgres 9.0 changed the handling of escape strings used with `bytea`: previous versions treated `\` in regular string literals such as `'\'` as escape characters, whereas newer versions use the [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/datatype-binary.html) `E'\'`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to your 9.X server configuration, you can change bytea_output variable to 'escape' on postgresql.conf:

```
bytea_output = 'escape'                 # hex, escape
```

Then restart Postgres 9.X server and dump the database as you do it normally. Finally, restore it on the 8.X server.

You can also change client connection variable just for the database dump action, but it may be outside scope.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL 9 backups are **not** backward compatible, and there are no options to enable this compatibility. I've been stuck on this problem for hours.

You'll need to figure out which statements are not compatible, and find their equivalent (if there's one) in PostgreSQL 8.

Another option, the better one, would be to upgrade your v8 to the latest v9.